# Selenium not finding tab link elements by various methods

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm having issues with Selenium locating a set of specific tab link elements by IDs or link text. Using Selenium, I'm trying to click/loop through each of the tabs ("DESCRIPTION AND PRICE", "FINISH", and "NOTES") and scrape the subsequent table (see screenshot).

[image]

Below is the HTML of the tabs. When my loop first loads the page, the "DESCRIPTION AND PRICE" tab is active, and the subsequent table is easily scraped with BeautifulSoup (by searching for the  with the specific table ID). However, after the "D+P" table is scraped, I try to click the "FINISH" tab with Selenium, I get the NoSucElementException error.

I hope to be able to click on the "FINISH" and "NOTES" tabs using the link text method (since the tabs are different from page to page). This results in the error.

> driver.find_element_by_link_text("FINISH").click()

I've also tried the ID method, but this fails too.

> driver.find_element_by_id("cphMain_tbTabs_rptTabs_lnkTab_1").click()

I've also tried various wait methods in case the element just wasn't yet loaded, although I get the same error when attempting to wait for an element ID, because it can't find the ID.

Another consideration is that I'm not seeing any mention of an iframe in the html.

```
<div id="cphMain_upTabs">

                    <div id="cphMain_divTabs" class="tabs">
                        <div id="cphMain_tbTabs_divTabs">

    <ul class="tabset">

    <li><a id="cphMain_tbTabs_rptTabs_lnkTab_0" class="tab active" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$tbTabs$rptTabs$ctl01$lnkTab&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-weight:bold;">DESCRIPTION AND PRICE</a></li>

    <li><a id="cphMain_tbTabs_rptTabs_lnkTab_1" class="tab" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$tbTabs$rptTabs$ctl02$lnkTab&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-weight:normal;">FINISH</a></li>

    <li><a id="cphMain_tbTabs_rptTabs_lnkTab_2" class="tab" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$tbTabs$rptTabs$ctl04$lnkTab&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-weight:normal;">NOTES</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the page url so I could take a look? From what you tried, I don't see why it wouldn't work so maybe there's something we aren't seeing?

Comment: The page url is behind a login, so I won't be able to share all the info. However, I think I found a solution with Try/Except logic. For whatever reason the issue seems to be with the first page in the list I'm trying to scrape. With that logic, we pass on the first page, and all subsequent pages get scraped as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue was with the first page I'm checking - I've added Try/Except logic and now I'm able to skip the first page and scrape the info for the subsequent pages. Not sure what the issue is with the first page...